# Magento 2 - Add shipping cost to mini cart

Tags: magento2.4, mini-cart, subtotal

How can we display the shipping cost in the mini cart subtotal?

At the moment we only have the subtotal in the mini cart.

We tried a lot in the mini cart tax template;

```
/Magento_Tax/web/template/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals.html

data-bind="html: cart().shippingAmount"
data-bind="html: cart()['shipping_amount']"
```

But we can not get the value, what are we missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at a 2.4.2 site, the shipping amount isn't stored with the **cart** data used by that template.

(Also, I don't think shipping cost is calculated until the customer visits the cart page, even if it is flat rate. But that is a separate issue.)

The template's **cart** data is set in:

*vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals.js*

```
initialize: function () {
    this._super();
    this.cart = customerData.get('cart');
}
```

You would have to make **cart-data** available to the template and get the shipping amount from its **totals**.

The data included in each can be seen by running the following in the browser console:

```
require([
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function(
    customerData
) {
    console.log(customerData.get('cart')());
    console.log(customerData.get('cart-data')());
});
```

To make **cart-data** available to the template, you would need to override *totals.js* with a modified copy in your design files, i.e.:

*app/design/frontend/[your theme]/luma/Magento_Tax/web/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals.js*

In the following example, **cart-data** is made available.

Since **cart-data** may be empty, a wrapper is also added to return the shipping amount only when available *(Note the comma added between `initialize` and `getShippingAmount`)*:

```
initialize: function () {
    this._super();
    this.cart = customerData.get('cart');
    this.cartData = customerData.get('cart-data');
},

getShippingAmount: function() {
    if (this.cartData() && this.cartData().totals) {
        return this.cartData().totals.shipping_amount;
    }
}
```

With these changes in place, the template supports, e.g.:

`data-bind="html: getShippingAmount()`

You could also create a mixin or override in a custom extension.

E.g.

*app/code/Your/Extension/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js*:

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals': {
                'Your_Extension/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals-mixin': true
            },
        }
    }
};
```

*app/code/Your/Extension/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals-mixin.js*:

```
define([
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return function (Component) {
        return Component.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                this.cartData = customerData.get('cart-data');
            },

            getShippingAmount: function() {
                if (this.cartData() && this.cartData().totals) {
                    return this.cartData().totals.shipping_amount;
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it also now possible to check if the customer is loggedin? isLoggedIn seems not working.

Comment: Sadly it does not work well with logged out customers, then we face the JS error: 
`Message: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'cartData().totals.shipping_amount')`

Comment: I updated the answer to account for situations where cartData().totals.shipping_amount would cause an error because the information is unavailable. As far as I can tell, this is true for not-logged-in customers until they visit the cart page.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfect now!